# Magento 2 Product Attribute Swatch Image

Tags: magento2, attributes

I have created a product **attribute** that is using an image **swatch** for each **attribute** value.

**My question is how can I go about retrieving the image swatch URL from the attribute within my product view?**

I am familiar with how to retrieve an attribute value but can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the image swatch.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve that value, you need the next in your block or viewModel (https://www.yireo.com/blog/1856-viewmodels-in-magento-2)

```
...

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data as CatalogData;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media;

...

/**
 * @var Data
 */
private $swatchesHelper;

/**
 * @var Media
 */
private $swatchesHelperMedia;

/**
 * @var CatalogData
 */
private $catalogHelperData;

...

/**
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getSwatchImage()
{
    $product = $this->catalogHelperData->getProduct(); //This depends of as you want do it,but you can do it on this way
    if ($product->getSwatchAttribute()) {
        $image = $this->swatchesHelper->getSwatchesByOptionsId([$product->getSwatchAttribute()]);
        if (current($image)['value']) {
            return $this->swatchesHelperMedia->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_thumb', current($image)['value']);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**swatch_attribute** is the attribute code.